# Why does my program skip commands?

Tags: java

```
    System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
    x=user.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("What is the second number? ");
    y=user.nextInt();
   System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Answer yes/no. Would you like to multiply? ");
    ans=user.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    if(ans.equals("yes")||ans.equals("y"))
    {
        System.out.println(x*y);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("How about division? ");
        ans=user.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
```

===============

this is the output

What is the first number? 6

What is the second number? 5

Answer yes/no. Would you like to multiply? How about division?

========
Why does it not wait to take user input after the mulitplication question?

Comment: Read this article I wrote some time ago: [Using nextInt() before nextLine()](https://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/) for more information.

Comment: @Christian That link leads to a 404.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Try again. I was trying to format it.

Comment: @Christian Much better.